# Why can't I use a list of functions returning a generic class with different type parameters in C#

Tags: c#, list, function, generics, type-conversion

I'm working on a C# project where I have an interface `IAnimal` and two classes `Dog` and `Cat` that implement this interface. I also have a generic class `Zoo<T>` where `T` is a type that implements `IAnimal`.

Here's the relevant code:

```cs
public interface IAnimal { /* ... */ }

public class Dog : IAnimal { /* ... */ }

public class Cat : IAnimal { /* ... */ }

public class Zoo<T> where T : IAnimal { /* ... */ }
```

I'm trying to create two functions `CreateZooOfDog` and `CreateZooOfCat` that return a `Zoo<Dog>` and `Zoo<Cat>` respectively. I then want to add these functions to a list and call them in a loop. Here's what I tried:

```cs
public Zoo<Dog> CreateZooOfDog() { /* ... */ }

public Zoo<Cat> CreateZooOfCat() { /* ... */ }

var zooes = new List<Func<Zoo<IAnimal>>>();

Func<Zoo<Dog>> zooOfDog = () => program.CreateZooOfDog();
Func<Zoo<Cat>> zooOfCat = () => program.CreateZooOfCat();

zooes.Add(zooOfDog);
zooes.Add(zooOfCat );
```

However, I'm getting a compile-time error on the `CreateZooOfDog` and `CreateZooOfCat` " .

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening since `Dog` and `Cat` both implement `IAnimal`. Could someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?"

If i modify the list to List, then i can add both Cat/Or to the List.

[image]

Comment: Likely a casting issue. Can you try casting `(Func<Zoo<Dog>>)program.CreateZooOfDog();`

Also, the point of generics is that a single method can create any type. So having  a method that specifically creates a `Cat` and one for `Dog` defeats the purpose of this. Might as well just have the return type be a `Cat` or `Dog` for those methods. Or just create a single method which would make this more useful for generics.

Comment: `Zoo<Dog>` is not a `Zoo<IAnimal>` unless `T`  is contravariant. `public interface IZoo<out T> where T : IAnimal`

Answer (score 0):

The point of generics is so multiple methods do not need to be created in order to return a type `T`. Having a specific method that accepts an `IAnimal` but returns only a `Dog` type, then one more for returning a `Cat` type defeats the purpose of using generics.

It would make more sense to have a single method that accepts type `IAnimal` determines the type that needs to be returned and return it.

```
public interface IAnimal {  }

public class Dog : IAnimal {  }

public class Cat : IAnimal {  }

public class Zoo<T> where T : IAnimal {  }
```

```
public Zoo<T> CreateZoo<T>(T animal)
{
    //Determine type T that needs to be returned 
    if (animal is Cat)
        //
    if (animal is Dog)
        //
}
```

Then just cast to whichever type is needed.

```
Dog dog = (Dog)zooObj.CreateZoo(new Dog());
Cat cat = (Cat)zooObj.CreateZoo(new Cat());
```

This would be a better use of generics and reduce multiple functions that effectively do the same thing. Other functions that are specific to `Dog`, or specific to `Cat` could be private and once the `CreateZoo` function determines the type that is needed to be returned, can rely on those private encapsulated methods.

Comment: I have updated my question, if the List is an List<Interface>, i can add both cat/dog to it, but when List<Func<Interface>> it's not work :(